# Use function input as code Python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have this function (SQLAlchemy):

```
# table: Table to search (should be the class name)
# column: filter to use
# search: search term
#
# Returns a list [object] with the found entries in the database
# Uses the SQL LIKE statement

def search(table, column, search):
    results = dbsession.query(table).filter(column.like('%' + search + '%')).all()
    return results
```

So this search function searches in the class 'table', uses the filter 'column' and searches for 'search'. The problem I'm having now is that if I enter a value for 'column' (wich is actually not a string but a piece of code) I always get an error that the name doesn't exists:

```
  users =  search(User, fname, 'Jo')
NameError: name 'fname' is not defined
```

Does anybody know how to code this properly?

Comment: That is a runtime error because you did not define `fname`, *not* a sqlalchemy problem.

Comment: alright, but how should I do it then? I want to search in the fname column?

Comment: If you have the table object, why not just grab it from there? `User.fname` is the column..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `users =  search(User, User.fname, 'Jo')` instead.